# What does "std::decay_t<U> (until C++20) std::remove_cvref_t<U> (since C++20)" mean?

Tags: c++, option-type

Can someone explain to me in detail what this sentence means?

> ```
> template< class U = T >
> optional& operator=( U&& value );
> ```
>
> 4) ...The function does not participate in overload resolution unless 
>   `std::decay_t<U>` (until C++20) `std::remove_cvref_t<U>` (since C++20) is not `std::optional<T>`...

<sup>([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D))</sup>

In the 4th version, what does it mean to write "`std::decay_t<U>` (until C++20) `std::remove_cvref_t<U>` (since C++20)" without any verb? Is there a typo?

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Could you , please, explain the part "The function does not participate in overload resolution unless"

Comment: "Does not participate in overload resolution" means  that some other overload of operator= for example (4) is selected when you assign some non-optional to optional.

Comment: I try to understand that deeply.

Answer (score 3):

It's subtle—there's a box around the two classes that indicates a sub-phrase. Pretend there's an "or" between them and read it like this:

> The function does not participate in overload resolution unless [ `std::decay_t<U>` (until C++20) or `std::remove_cvref_t<U>` (since C++20) ] is not `std::optional<T>`...

You could read it as two alternate sentences:

- The function does not participate in overload resolution unless `std::decay_t<U>` is not `std::optional<T>`... <sup>(until C++20)</sup>
- The function does not participate in overload resolution unless `std::remove_cvref_t<U>` is not `std::optional<T>`... <sup>(since C++20)</sup>

<sup>(In C++20 they tightened up the spec and replaced `decay` with `remove_cvref`. The two do essentially the same thing but the latter is more surgically precise. `decay`, like `remove_cvref`, removes qualifiers; but it also turns arrays into pointers, which isn't germane here.)</sup>

In English, it's essentially saying:

> The function does not participate in overload resolution unless `U`—ignoring `&`, `&&`, `const`, and `volatile`—is not `std::optional<T>`...

In other words, overload (4) is only useable under certain conditions. If those conditions aren't met then perfect forwarding is taken off the table; presumably, [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is used to disable it.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining even more in English. I appreciate that care. I understand this part now. And the only thing that remains to clarify for me is the part of the sentence which says in both cases "the function does not participate in overload resolution". Could you, please explain that to me ? thank you